# fancy the notion of a disliked human getting a treat

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "fancy the notion" as "appreciate the idea". Am I on the right track?

> DECEPTION IN THE WILD
> HOMO SAPIENS IS NOT THE ONLY SPECIES THAT LIES. DISHONESTY ABOUNDS IN THE ANIMAL KINGDOM  ....................
> As anyone who has lived with dogs knows, they are not great at forgoing beloved foods. Apparently the dogs in this experiment wanted to increase their chances of getting the desirable food later— and knew that deceiving the selfish Ms. Competitor might just increase their odds. Maybe, too, Heberlein says, they just did not **fancy the notion of a disliked human getting a treat**. Whatever their mo- tivation, the dogs’ deception was tactical.

Source: Scientific American (Sep.2019)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on exactly the right track. In your example, they are saying that the dog doesn't like the idea.

To "fancy the notion" means to approve of an idea or situation. As in your example, the phrase "fancy the notion" is often used in the negative, to talk about situations someone doesn't approve of. There is often an element of mild humor implied when it is used in this way. For instance, the following sentence means that the subject didn't want to be in a traffic accident:

> He didn't fancy the notion of a trip to the hospital, so he got out of the way of oncoming traffic.

Fancy the notion is also often used in questions, such as
the following, which is a rhetorical question appearing in an advertisement:

> Fancy the notion of being pampered this Valentine's Day?

Related expressions include saying that something "tickles your fancy," which means it appeals to you. One can also "take a fancy to" something, which means that they have come to like it.